# Prevent processes from running on GPU

Tags: process, nvidia

I haven't found a straightforward way of preventing a process X from running on GPU. In my case, I want to exclude compiz window manager and some other processes from running on my nVidia GPU.

There are, indeed, application profiles (in nVidia X server settings), but using that, one can just fine tune some OpenGL settings, not completely exclude the process from running on GPU.

Is there a way of achieving this? Is Bumblebee the (only) solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by using `bumblebee-nvidia`.